# Java program as windows service

Tags: java, windows

I have a java program which need to be run as a service. How do I do that easily?

Answer (score 7):

Good explanations in [this article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32068) -- including the pointer to the `Java Service Wrapper` open-source component that makes it easy.

Answer (score 2):

Write a service in C/C++ and load the JVM from that. Or you can use [some tool](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32068) that wraps your Java application to a service.